# Interface Definition Language

Tags: idl

Can anybody explain to me what is meant by Interface Definition Language on a high level. Why it is used and how and where. 
Any ebook, concrete definitions and examples will also help.

Anybody who have worked/used this please share your knowledge. No googled resource please.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Gaurav

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670630/what-is-idl

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is IDL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670630/what-is-idl)

Answer (score 2):

IDL is a Interface Definition Language and is generally used for defining programming language independent interfaces. A special compiler creates interfaces (or similar) for a specific language, i.e. Java.

IDL is often used in distributed systems, for example in the UNO Framework used by OpenOffice