# invoke mozIAsyncLivemarks.idl with Java

Tags: java, c++, firefox, corba, idl

How can I Programmatically , directly, invoke `mozIAsyncLivemarks.idl` with Java?  It seems that an [IDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670630/what-is-idl) comes from C++.

While I'm aware of [Rome](http://rometools.github.io/rome/), I'd like to use Firefox if possible.  If it's not possible, or extremely difficult, to do this with Java, that would be an acceptable answer as well.

This is somewhat like using CORBA?

http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/places/mozIAsyncLivemarks.idl

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/idl/GShome.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla XPIDL files are somewhat similar in syntax to OMG IDL (the standard used for CORBA object interfaces) but that's where the relationship to CORBA ends.

You should consult [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/XPIDL) for more information on XPIDL.

Comment: the link to `XPCOM` says that there multiple language bindings.  How can I use Java bindings to make calls on this type of interface?